# Is it possible to change the direction vertical slider in swiper slider? I want to have both top to bottom and bottom to top option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I'm working on a page that contains two vertical sliders. But on clicking down arrow button or on mouse scroll, I want one to slide up words (bottom to top) and the other downwards (top to bottom). How can I implement this?

My code basically looks something like this:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-v swiper-left">
            <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-v"></div>
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">Vertical Slide 1</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Vertical Slide 2</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Vertical Slide 3</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Vertical Slide 4</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Vertical Slide 5</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-v2 swiper-right">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">Vertical Slide 1</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Vertical Slide 2</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Vertical Slide 3</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Vertical Slide 4</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Vertical Slide 5</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
 </div>
```

Script like this:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      direction: 'vertical',

    });
    var swiperV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-v', {
      direction: 'vertical',
      spaceBetween: 50,
      keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination-v',
        clickable: true,
      },
      loop: true,
    });
    var swiperV2 = new Swiper('.swiper-container-v2', {
      direction: 'vertical',
      spaceBetween: 50,
      keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination-v',
        clickable: true,
      },
      loop: true,
      reverseDirection: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [this swiper](https://swiperjs.com/api/#navigation) there is the `navigation` object you need to add to your configuration.

Something like in the example the guys that are developing the Swiper are reporting in their API:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
    }
});
```

If you want to invert the standard swiping (direction of swipe) you just need to swap the classes that reference your arrows in the configuration.

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-next'
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't have the previous & next buttons, but have bullet pagination. Is it possible to configure the same for bullets as well?

Comment: Try with the classes you are using for the pagination